# Reflecting code changes in docker containers

Tags: express, docker

I have a basic hello world Node application written on express. I have just dockerised this application by creating a basic dockerfile in the applications root directory. I created a docker image, and then ran that image to run it in a running container

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:0.10-onbuild
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./bin/www"]

sudo docker build -t docker-express
sudo docker run --name test-container -d -p 80:3000 docker-express
```

I can access the web application. My question is.. When I made code changes to my application, eg change 'hello world' to 'hello bob', my changes are not reflected within the running container.

What is a good development workflow to update changes in the container? Surely I shouldn't have to delete and rebuild the images after each change?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Check out the section on [Sharing Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).  You should be able to share your host volume with the docker container and then any time you need a change you can just restart the server (or have something restart it for you!).

Your command would look something like: `sudo docker run -v /src/webapp:/webapp --name test-container -d -p 80:3000 docker-express`

Which mounts /src/webapp (on the host) to /webapp (in the container).

Comment: Thanks :). If i want CMD ["node", "./bin/www"] to run correctly inside the container using this mounting technique, where should I mount my application inside the container?  What is the best practice?

Comment: I've yet to find a good reason to not just mount it right at the root (as the example shows as well).  Your command will execute when you first build and run the container, but for subsequent changes, the dockerfile won't actually be used.  What you'll want to do is something like `docker exec <image_id> node ./bin/www`.  Alternatively, if you want to open a shell in the conatiner (so you don't have to do `docker exec` all the time) you can do `docker exec -ti <image_id> /bin/bash` and then manually restart the server whenever needed.